# Lumia 520 in Airplane mode and IMEI lost after Lumia Device Recovery

Tags: lumia-520

First, my Lumia 520 went into FLIGHT MODE. When I repaired with LUMIA DEVICE RECOVERY TOOL, the IMEI number of the phone was lost. After hitting *#06# it showed nothing.

I am told to throw instrument in YAMUNA. Such is the manufacturing and maintenance of NOKIA phones after being taken over by MICROSOFT. What should I do ? Does anyone have a solution to my issue ? I also beg MICROSOFT to help me in this regard. I am eagerly waiting for a solution.

Comment: have you tried doing a hard reset?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if this tool still works, but you could try the Nokia Software Updater for Retail: http://www.mediafire.com/file/5g4iqpbelwwpu6e/NokiaSoftwareUpdaterForRetail_4.3.2.exe

Answer (score 0):

No. You have to contact nearest Microsoft device care centre for help. It's a software problem but the solution is to change the hardware. I also faced this problem long time ago. They replace some part of the phone with new one and make it workable again. But for me they charge me Rs. 1250. But after that my phone work flawlessly.